# Openshift maximum php post size

Tags: php, post, openshift

I've made my application that send data trough post to opeshift webserver. Tipically I tweak the php.ini to increase the 2M limit. Openshift seems to not relay to this file, or at least I was not able to find it. Also the limit seems bigger than 2M (I was able to uplaod 3.something MB on a test). Do you now which the limit is and if it is possible to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the max upload size by creating a phpinfo page (http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and then viewing it and looking for the `upload_max_filesize` key, which on an OpenShift Online small gear is 200M.  Since you do not have access to the php.ini file, you can try using `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');` in one of your PHP files and see if that helps.